# What is Dark Souls' frame rate on PS3 and Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, dark-souls, framerate

I'm musing about possibly getting the remaster on Switch, running at   30fps and I'm curious about the original frame rate on the Xbox 360 and PS3.

Comment: Hopefully I didn't edit the post too heavily. The title is now more SEO-optimal as well.

Comment: Depends, in Blight Town or outside of Blight Town?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about Xbox 360 but on PS3 it has 30 fps at 720p.

Comment: The original Dark Souls game was locked at 30 FPS for all platforms, but on PC you were able to unlock it by using DSFix.

Answer (score 1):

Locked at 30fps [according to Digital Foundry](https://www.eurogamer.net/digitalfoundry-darks-souls-pc-tech-comparison) ([performance analysis video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhoDHdJdcAs)):

> [...] at a locked 30 frames per second, just as with the PS3 and 360 entries.